# Scanned text blurred characters correction

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-morphology

Could you please advice what image processing transform can I use in order to correct character blurring after text scanning? Afterwards, i am planning to remove uneven background illumination using top-hat transforms.

[image]

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61850319/edit) the post to include your own effort into solving this problem. [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: It is unlikely that you’ll be able to fix this post-scanning. You should improve the scanning instead.

Answer (score 2):

You need spatially dependent deconvolution. I think, the point scattering function (PSF) here is ellipse (in left part  of image).

Comment: For high-quality scanning, it is better to use CCD scanners, rather than CIS.

Comment: Explained [here](https://www.cs.umd.edu/users/oleary/reprints/j45.pdf). These types of restoring techniques are only possible if the spatially variant blurring function or your PSF is known. The OP's question feels like that is not the case here!